# Why does "print" prints from right to left?

Tags: php

Can anyone please explain to me how this works:

```
<?php
    print 5 . print 6 . print 7;
?>
```

it prints: `76151`

I know the `1` is the return value from the `print` function, but why are the functions called in reverse order?

Comment: Can I ask how this question came about? Is it a simplified version of another issue you're dealing with?

Comment: Note that it prints the text, then returns `1`, so you can't `print()` another `print()` or you'll get trailing `1` junk.

Comment: @MikeB I just played around with the print function. I also found a similar question in a php certification book (but without any explanation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this occurs because the dot operator is [left-associative](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

The expression would look like this with parenthesis:

```
print 5 . (print 6 . (print 7));
```

Comment: +1 Good link. That's the third time I've seen *left-associative* answers this week. I just reviewed them all.

Comment: I know this page,  but I have never understood this left/right thing, now I know better, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is evaluating from right to left.

The trace is similar to this:

```
print (5 . print 6 . print 7)
```

print 7 evaluates first, printing 7 and returning 1.

```
print (5 . print 6 . 1)
```

This traces to print 61 and returning 1 Lastly:

```
print (5 . 1)
```

And thus you have 76151.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression can be written like this:

```
print (5 . print (6 . print 7));
```

`print 61` and `print 7` are return boolean `1`, thats why `1` is also printed